# HTML Remove Img Padding (display: block not working)

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the padding from an . The style "display: block" (mentioned in many other solutions) doesn't seem to solve the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://imgur.com/CahbpxJ.jpg" width="100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By just adding `display: block` you in no way override padding. A separate `padding: ...` style must be applied.

Comment: You want to remove the default body margin coming from the browser stylesheet. And you want to learn how to use your browsers dev tools, to find out where such stuff is coming from yourself in the future ;-)

Comment: You must be seeing the empty space because of the browser styles. You can reset them. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from CBroe's comment. The body tag has its own default margin. To fix the problem add this in the style tag:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: so your problem fixed as well ?

Comment: well i dont think this deserve that you answer your own question ... it's something well known and with a small search or looking at dev tools we can find it

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: You could provide more information what's going on here. That might not be clear for the OP